# Swift 3 User Defaults set dictionary crash

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, userdefaults

I have worked with Userdefaults many times before but in this case can't seem to figure out what would cause this crash to occur even though it is such a simple case.

Goal: UserDefaults.standard.set a dictionary with a value of an array of dictionary's

```
struct UDKey {
  static let activityCount = "ActivityCount"
}

class MyClass {
  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

  func initialize() {
    let years = [ 2017: [[1:2],
                         [2:4],
                         [3:6],
                         [4:8],
                         [5:10],
                         [6:12],
                         [7:14],
                         [8:16],
                         [9:17],
                         [10:18],
                         [11:19],
                         [12:20]]]

    if defaults.value(forKey: UDKey.activityCount) == nil {
      defaults.set(years, forKey: UDKey.activityCount) // Crash - lldb
    }
  }
}
```

I have attempted setting others values with success, such as simple integers and strings. but this dictionary with a value of an array of dictionary's is having a problem.
What could be the cause for a UserDefaults Crash when setting a value.

Comment: A dictionary can only be saved to `UserDefaults` if all of the keys are `String` and all of the values are the types listed in the documentation for `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Ah Thank You! Fixed The Issue Immediately

Comment: You can save any value confirming to Codable protocol into UserDefaults